# Can't reach 'this' in karma test for angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm working on a small project and I currently ran into an issue using this over $scope. I'm not sure which is best but I'm not stuck because karma won't find 'this' in my controller when I write up a jasmine test. Here is my jasmine test code:

```
'use strict';
 describe('PhoneListCtrl', function() {
     beforeEach(module('phoneCtrlModule'));

      it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller){
         var scope = {},
             ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope:scope});
      expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
      }));
 });
```

And here is the angular controller itself:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('phoneCtrlModule', []);

    app.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function() {
       this.phones = [
           {'name': 'Nexus S',
            'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
           {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
           {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
        ];
    });

 })();
```

I've tried making $scope equal to this.phones but it doesn't work. I'm a little confused as to how you could reach PhoneListCtrl.phones inside of a karma test.

Comment: Works for me http://plnkr.co/edit/IZjjoF?p=info You need to check `ctrl.phones.length`

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Silly me trying to be all complicated.

Answer (score 1):

keyword this here signifies the controller itself.
you can use this.phones in the test case as

phoneCtrlModule.phones

alternative to it is:

var scope;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$Controller){

```
$scope=$rootScope.$new();

var ctrl = $controller('phoneCtrlModule', {
        $scope: scope
    });
```

}));

expect(scope.phones.length).toEqual(3);